# Connecting to database asp.net web pages razor

Tags: asp.net, database, razor, database-connection

I am doing the tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/5-working-with-data

Code:

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("SmallBakery");
var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Product ORDER BY Name";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Small Bakery Products</title>
   <style>
   table, th, td {
     border: solid 1px #bbbbbb;
     border-collapse: collapse;
     padding: 2px;
   }
   </style>
 </head>
<body>
<h1>Small Bakery Products</h1>
<table>
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>Id</th>
           <th>Product</th>
           <th>Description</th>
   <th>Price</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       @foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString)){
        <tr>
           <td>@row.Id</td>
               <td>@row.Name</td>
               <td>@row.Description</td>
               <td>@row.Price</td>
        </tr>
       }
   </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I am always getting an error in the foreach-loop. Why? Can someone help me?

The database is called SmallBakery.mdf and the table is just called Product.

Comment: what type of error?

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Netzwerkbezogener oder instanzspezifischer Fehler beim Herstellen einer Verbindung mit SQL Server. Der Server wurde nicht gefunden, oder auf ihn kann nicht zugegriffen werden. Überprüfen Sie, ob der Instanzname richtig ist und ob SQL Server Remoteverbindungen zulässt. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Fehler beim Bestimmen des angegebenen Servers/der angegebenen Instanz)"

geworfen. 

In English: Server cant be found, error 26: Failed to connect to server - not found or no access

Answer (score 0):

This means your application can't establish connection to your database.
You need a reference to the `WebMatrix.Data.dll` assembly (which you probably have) and you also need a `using` directive for the `WebMatrix.Data` namespace at the top of the page:

```
@using Webmatrix.Data;
```

Alternatively, you can add a reference in the `web.config` file that exists in your views folder.This will import the Database class so you can use it without fully-qualifying the name.

Comment: but you are following webMatrix doc.